# Why isn't the LinkedList going through all entities?

Tags: java, collision-detection, collision

I am trying to develop collision detection. For some reason, the collision is working for the last entity in the LinkedList. I have tried my best to debug it using the console to see where it's stopping, but I had no luck. All the other entities are not working, only the last one is. Here is the code :

```
public class Player implements Entity {

Image player;

public float x = 100f;
public float y = 100f;

public boolean canGoLeft = true;
public boolean canGoRight = true;
public boolean canGoUp = true;
public boolean canGoDown = true;

public float speed = 0.15f;

public Rectangle leftRect;
public Rectangle rightRect;
public Rectangle topRect;
public Rectangle bottomRect;

int i = 0;

Entities entities = new Entities();

public Player() {

}

public void update(GameContainer game, int delta) {

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_D)) {
        if(canGoRight) {
            x += speed * delta; 
        }
    }

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A)) {
        if(canGoLeft) {
            x -= speed * delta;
        }
    }

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_W)) {
        if(canGoUp) {
            y -= speed * delta; 
        }
    }

    if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_S)) {
        if(canGoDown) {
            y += speed * delta;
        }
    }

    for(Entity entity : Game.entities.entities) {
        checkCollisions(entity);
    }

}

public void render(GameContainer game, Graphics g) {

    leftRect = new Rectangle(x, y + 5, 2, 80);
    rightRect = new Rectangle(x + 45, y + 5, 2, 80);
    topRect = new Rectangle(x + 6, y, 36, 2);
    bottomRect = new Rectangle(x + 6, y + 90, 36, 2);

    //rect = new Rectangle(200, 100, 60, 88);

    try {
        player = new Image("res/Player.png");
        player.setFilter(Image.FILTER_NEAREST);
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    player.draw(x, y, 60, 88);

    //g.draw(leftRect);
    //g.draw(rightRect);
    //g.draw(topRect);
    //g.draw(bottomRect);

}

public void checkCollisions(Entity entity) {

    // Collision Detection

    if(leftRect.intersects(entity.getRect())) {
        canGoLeft = false;
    }

    if(rightRect.intersects(entity.getRect())) {
        canGoRight = false;
    }

    if(topRect.intersects(entity.getRect())) {
        canGoUp = false;
    }

    if(bottomRect.intersects(entity.getRect())) {
        canGoDown = false;
    }



    if(!leftRect.intersects(entity.getRect())) {
        canGoLeft = true;
    }

    if(!rightRect.intersects(entity.getRect())) {
        canGoRight = true;
    }

    if(!topRect.intersects(entity.getRect())) {
        canGoUp = true;
    }

    if(!bottomRect.intersects(entity.getRect())) {
        canGoDown = true;
    }

}

public Rectangle getRect() {
    return null;
}
```

}

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting global values for whether you can go up down left and right.  So each entity is overwriting the same global variables, causing their state to be in the state of the last entity checked.  I think the best approach as this point is to assure all bools start true, then only set them to false as collisions happen.

```
public void update(GameContainer game, int delta) {
    //...


    canGoLeft = true;
    canGoRight = true;
    canGoDown = true;
    canGoUp = true;
    for(Entity entity : Game.entities.entities) {
        checkCollisions(entity);
    }

public void checkCollisions(Entity entity) {

    // Collision Detection
    if(leftRect.intersects(entity.getRect())) {
        canGoLeft = false;
    }

    if(rightRect.intersects(entity.getRect())) {
        canGoRight = false;
    }

    if(topRect.intersects(entity.getRect())) {
        canGoUp = false;
    }

    if(bottomRect.intersects(entity.getRect())) {
        canGoDown = false;
    }
}
```

(be sure to rid yourself of the conditions that are setting `canGoDirection` to true in cases of non-intersection as this will cause it to not work).

Comment: Oh sorry I totally misinterpreted what you were trying to do, let me update my answer.

Comment: @romofan23 OK sorry about that, the other answer was actually correct in your problem (I hadn't looked at all the code to fully understand your goal).  I updated with a sample of what *should* fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the boolean values every time. Instead, set them all to `true` beforehand and then mark the appropriate one `false` every time you detect a collision.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you explain more?